# How can I compare values from a pandas pivot table which have multi levels?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table, multi-level

Below is my pivot table. I need help in comparing values and get the result based on prop1>prop0 | prop2>prop0. I used the following query...
**Output[(Output.prop1 > Output.prop0) | (Output.prop2> Output.prop0)]**
I am getting error. I dont know where I am going wrong. Please help!

```
Dose              0              1           2
                  dose0  prop0  dose1 prop1  dose2 prop2
Organ  Diagnosis 
heart  xyz         1     0.05    0    0.00   0     0.00
Lung   ghi         0     0.00    0    0.00   1     0.03
Kidney def         0     0.00    1    0.03   0     0.00                         
skin   jkl         0     0.00    5    0.16   0     0.00
liver  abc         8     0.42    6    0.19   6     0.19
```

here is the sample code...

```
Organ  Diagnosis Dose
heart  xyz        0
kidney abc        1
liver  def        2
kidney qrs        1
liver  dfj        2
heart  gdh        0
heart  hdh        1
kidney edr        2
```

from the above table I created a pivot table 1 with dose0 and prop0.
Column dose0 based on count of dose '0' and prop0 is the calculated based on dose0/X. X is sum integer. Then I created  two more pivot tables  for dose1 and dose2 and concatenated them.

Comment: Do you really need the multiIndex? It looks like the second level already has the dose #s appended to the column names.

Comment: Dry `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` and trying again.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it. It is in the requirement.

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of your input data as text, along with the code that produces this pivot table? Alternatively, print `df_pivoted.to_dict()`  and paste the output in your question... it becomes hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: The output is concatenated from 3 pivot tables and the column dose is swapped to upper level,  and the comparison is done on final result. The query on the final result is.... Output[(Output.prop1 > Output.prop0) | (Output.prop2> Output.prop0)]

Comment: No, I get the query... It won't work however, because you're dealing with a MultiIndex. For best results and minimal headache, I'm asking for your data so I can give you a solution that works.

Comment: Okay.... :/ ....

Comment: I have edited the question above. Please view it and ask if you need more information

Comment: Yes, just one more thing. The code that creates the pivot table?

Comment: R1= pd.pivot-table(x1, index=[‘organ’, ‘diagnosis’], values = (dose0, prop0), columns = (‘Dose’))

Comment: Your code does not run on the data provided. Okay, let me take a stab: try this—`Output[(Output[1].prop1 > Output[0].prop0) | (Output[2].prop2> Output[0].prop0)]`

Comment: It still gives error:(

Comment: Hey sorry the code worked. I forgot to replace the query with capital letters. Thank you so much